# Error loading media_group message in pyrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, telegram, pyrogram

I'm creating userbot that should copy messages and forward them to another chat, but once i get album of photos(media_group), i cannot forward them to another chat.

Each function inside `if message.media_group.id` is triggered exactly as many times as the number of images in the album, like:

*Input:*

```
i = message.id
print(i)
```

*Output:*

```
4384
4385
4386
```

I've tried `app.get_media_group(chat_id, message_id=mess.id)` but it works same - multiple times. The problem is that I can't forward due to it works multiple times and it just sends me same picture multiple times. Also I've tried with list, tuple - also couldn't get it. Can anyone help please?